# Does number of processes affect sequential execution for Messenger?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony5, symfony-messenger

We have a simple use case: we need to consume messages in the queue sequentially (message #1 finishes execution before message #2 starts execution).

Suggested supervisor configuration in Symfony docs is:

```
;/etc/supervisor/conf.d/messenger-worker.conf
[program:messenger-consume]
command=php /path/to/your/app/bin/console messenger:consume async --time-limit=3600
user=ubuntu
numprocs=2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
```

Does `numprocs=2` mean that 2 workers will consume the messages "simultaneously", i.e. worker 2 will start execution of message #2 before message #1 is finished?

If yes, is there any way to keep 2 workers (if we need simultaneous execution for some other message type) and still have the messages of this specific type be executed sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to process messages in strict sequence, what advantage would you get from having multiple consumer processes?

Process 2 would always need to wait on 1 to finish... so in essence no more than one process would run at the same time. No matter how many processes you are running, no parallelism advantage would be gained, since they would be effectively blocking each other.

If you need to process your queue messages in strict sequence, just use a single consumer process.

Comment: So, you are saying 2 processes give you parallelism? Basically, this is what I'd like to find out. To answer your question: I might need strict sequence for one Message type and parallelism for another.

Comment: Yes, having multiple processes is for parallelism. There is no other use.

Comment: I did, thanks. And now to answer my own question: If one wants parallelism for some message types and sequence for others, one can create different transports with separate supervisor entries.